# Saving parsing and striping metadata in NSString

Tags: ios, parsing, nsstring

I have some dynamic string that I am getting in my app. One example is below. (??? = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) In this example, numbers are supposed to be subscripts. Since I know this piece of information I am manually drawing them with NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName just fine. However in the future there will be strings where I will have to set subscript dynamically for certain strings. I am looking for a way to pass subscript information in the string and then parsing this info and finally striping away this part of the string because it's metadata.

How should I go with this? I can most definitely ask the guy on the backend to pass me string in any shape I want. Looking for suggestions.

Thanks.

```
self.statement1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"??? = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4"];


NSInteger start = 0;

for (NSString *component in [self.statement1String componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
    NSRange checkRange = NSMakeRange(start, self.statement1String.length - start);
    NSRange range = [self.statement1String rangeOfString:component options:0 range:checkRange];
    NSLog(@"range is %@ for string %@", NSStringFromRange(range), component);
    QWZTerm *term = [[QWZTerm alloc] initWithRangeValue:[NSValue valueWithRange:range]];
    term.termString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",component];
    [tempArray addObject:term];

    start = range.location + range.length;
}

    [self.statementTextStorage setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Source Sans Pro" size:30]
                                               , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-10} range:NSMakeRange(7, 1)];
    [self.statementTextStorage setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Source Sans Pro" size:30]
                                               , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-10} range:NSMakeRange(12, 1)];
    [self.statementTextStorage setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Source Sans Pro" size:30]
                                               , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-10} range:NSMakeRange(17, 1)];
    [self.statementTextStorage setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Source Sans Pro" size:30]
                                               , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-10} range:NSMakeRange(22, 1)];
```

Comment: Just use an established markup language, like HTML? "??? = n<sub>1</sub>..."

Comment: or I guess just custom xml because I will need custom tags in the future like <additionOperator> <subtractionOperator> etc.  So probably couple of dropdowns and textboxes on the web end that fills the statement (string) and keep this in the DB and converts this into xml whenever from client side I'd like to pull this info? I guess if I map this into model objects I don't even have to clean up the string, I can just re-create it from my model objects. Does this make sense?

Comment: Makes sense to me. Using XML means you don't have to write your own parsing code, which is always a pain in the ass.

Comment: Okay, great looks like I do have a plan for tomorrow! thanks Josh! Can you put your response in the answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, but may I suggest that you come back and post an answer yourself when you've got a more concrete solution? My comment doesn't amount to much more than a suggestion; I don't feel like it would make a particularly high-quality answer.